# Loading one dimensional data into a Dense layer in a sequential Keras model

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have the results of a trained model, ending in a Flatten layer in numpy output files.
I try to load them and use them as inputs of a Dense layer.

```
train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_flat_features_train.npy'))
train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_train_samples / 2))
#
validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_flat_features_validation.npy'))
validation_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_validation_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples / 2))
#
top_m  = Sequential()
top_m.add(Dense(2,input_shape=train_data.shape[1:], activation='sigmoid', name='top_dense1'))
top_m.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#
top_m.fit(train_data, train_labels,
    nb_epoch=nb_epoch, batch_size=my_batch_size,
    validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
```

However I get the following error message:

```
    ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected top_dense1 to have
 shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (13, 1)
```

My input dimensions are (16,1536) - 16 images for this limited trail run, 1536 features.

```
>>> train_data.shape
(16, 1536)
```

The dense layer should expect a one dimensional 1536 long array.

```
>>> train_data.shape[1]
1536
```

What should I do?
Many thanks!

Comment: what is train_data.shape ?

Comment: Good point, I added that information to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found my problem - I did not define the lables correctly. I have switched the model compilation to a sparse categorical crossentropy mode.

my current code is

```
def train_top_model():
    train_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_flat_features_train.npy'))
    train_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_train_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_train_samples / 2))
#
    validation_data = np.load(open('bottleneck_flat_features_validation.npy'))
    validation_labels = np.array([0] * (nb_validation_samples / 2) + [1] * (nb_validation_samples / 2))
#
    top_m  = Sequential()
    top_m.add(Dense(2,input_shape=train_data.shape[1:], activation='softmax', name='top_dense1'))
    top_m.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
#
    top_m.fit(train_data, train_labels,
    nb_epoch=nb_epoch, batch_size=my_batch_size,
    validation_data=(validation_data, validation_labels))
```

Now it works and converges.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to compile and fit top_m instead of model?

Comment: The error has changed to

 ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected top_dense1 to have shape (None, 2) but got array with shape (13, 1)

As described in the corrected question.